# How to compute perverse sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, homology-cohomology

In the [video](http://sms.cam.ac.uk/media/523370/), from 49:00 to the end of the video, there is an example of computing $IC(S, L)$ and equivariant local systems. I don't understand some parts of the computations.

Let $X$ be the variety of $3 \times 3$ nilpotent matrices and let $SL_3$ acts on it by conjugation. Then the orbit of $$ \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$ is of real dimension dimension $12$. Why the equivariant local systems of $S_p$ are ${\underline{\mathbb{C}}}_X$, $L_1$, $L_2$ (representations of $\mathbb{Z}/3$)? How to show that $IC(S_p, {\underline{\mathbb{C}}}_X) = {\underline{\mathbb{C}}}_X[6]$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_p$ be the $\mathrm{SL}_3$-orbit of the regular nilpotent element $e\in\mathrm{sl}_3$ in the question. Then, the stabilizer of the action consists of matrices:
$$N:=\{\begin{pmatrix}\zeta&x&y\\&\zeta&x\\&&\zeta\end{pmatrix}:\zeta^3=1,x,y\in\mathbb C\},$$
which has three components. Thus, $\mathrm{SL}_3/N\cong S_p$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/3$, since the universal cover is $\mathrm{SL}_3/N^0$, where $N^0$ is the connected component of $N$. Indeed, $N$ is contractible, so $\pi_0(\mathrm{SL}_3/N)\cong\pi_0(\mathrm{SL}_3)=1$.

Now, local systems on $S_p$ are simply representations of $\pi_0(S_p)=\mathbb Z/3$, so there are three such representations, as described in the talk.